# Mock jetpack ViewModel for unit tests using Dagger2 (Robolectric)

Tags: android, mvvm, dagger-2, android-jetpack

So I'm trying to write a unit test for my Activity using Robolectric, however I have no idea how to provide a mocked viewmodel seeing as how my vm is instantiated directly in the class. This is due to the fact that jetpack's lifecycle aware ViewModel requires a Provider class to instantiate. So, I'm essentially injecting the custom provider and then using that to create my ViewModel. I've looked at other examples but they all seem extremely confusing. How do I achieve this?

```
class ActivityEpisodeList : AppCompatActivity() {

        @Inject
        lateinit var vmFactory: ViewModelProvider.Factory

        private lateinit var vm: ActivityViewModel


        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_episode_list)

            MvvmDaggerApp.get(this).appComponent.inject(this)

            vm = ViewModelProviders.of(this, vmFactory)[ActivityViewModel::class.java]
    }
}
```

This is how I'm creating my ViewModel:

```
@Module
abstract class ViewModelModule {

    @Binds
    internal abstract fun bindViewModelFactory(factory: ViewModelFactory): ViewModelProvider.Factory

    @Binds
    @IntoMap
    @ViewModelKey(ActivityViewModel::class)
    internal abstract fun postListViewModel(viewModel: ActivityViewModel): ViewModel

}


@Singleton
class ViewModelFactory @Inject constructor(private val viewModels: MutableMap<Class<out ViewModel>, Provider<ViewModel>>) : ViewModelProvider.Factory {

    override fun <T : ViewModel> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T = viewModels[modelClass]?.get() as T
}

@Target(AnnotationTarget.FUNCTION, AnnotationTarget.PROPERTY_GETTER, AnnotationTarget.PROPERTY_SETTER)
@kotlin.annotation.Retention(AnnotationRetention.RUNTIME)
@MapKey
internal annotation class ViewModelKey(val value: KClass<out ViewModel>)
```

Comment: Can you show us your unit test class?

Comment: I ran into a similar issue. The problem here is that the activity knows how it is being injected. Try looking into Dagger Android, it will allow you to inject field dependencies into your activities. It will require a good amount of refactoring though.

Comment: @SeanBlahovici I am currently using field injection in the above example. Or did you mean some sort of constructor injection?

Answer (score 2):

You should inject a Test View Model from the module which appComponent is using to create dependencies here.

Do not create the viewmodel yourself. Create 2 modules for appComponent one which provides the original dependencies and other with test/mock dependencies. Something like this -

```
@Module
public AppModule {
      public ViewModel appViewModel() { // return original here}
}

  @Module
public TestAppModule extends AppModule {
      public ViewModel appViewModel() { // return test/mock here}
}
```

In your test when you create Your AppComponent pass TestAppModule instead of AppModule, then you will get mocked dependencies.

Comment: My component is being initialised in the Application class (MvvmDaggerApp). I'm not sure what you mean. I cannot create it in my test class.

Comment: For unit tests , you will need to create it in your Test Initialization code . For example, in some method annotated with `@Setup` in case of Mockito.

Comment: appComponent is still being called in onCreate of my Activity. I don't understand how I will be able to provide another component to my Activity. Can you please explain with a code example?

Comment: Kinda late to the party, but I've almost lost my mind solving same problem. You must create another Application for testing purposes, that will extend your production Application. There you override creation of the component to return TestComponent. And the icing on the cake - in your tests, you add annotation on whole test class like 
@Config(application = TestApplication::class)
Hope it helps somebody :)